# How to parallel 2032 coin battery without removing the dead one?

Tags: batteries

I have device that run with 2032 coin battery but right now battery is dead/empty I want to know how to parallel new one without remove the empty one to avoid wipe out data. or a way to charge the empty non rechargeable coin battery without remove it from it socket.
Thanks for your reply

NB:  it's my first question hope to not be kicked after my first question :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a physical or electrical challenge?  The battery ESR rises sharply when Vbat has drops < 80% you can boost it. Temporarily

Comment: Show us a photo of the device.

Comment: Like this (ibb.co/dmjRhWq)

Comment: that photo doesn't actually show how the old battery comes out.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is some sort of secuity token, the batterty does not look top be user servicable,  you might be able to find a teardown on the net that shows how to access the battery without triggering a reset.

Comment: I just make a new pic of the opposite side and there is two same metal stuff don't know if they are all negative or positive + negative it's not write anything and if I open it more the device will be not usable ibb.co/XZkRWDv

Comment: the terminal at the back is positive - it has a "+" shaped hole in the middle, those on the front look like the negaive terminals.

Comment: in the topp picture the  battery flides to the right to come out of that clip, but there is plastic blocking this path,

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd put a power supply on the battery slightly above the batterys voltage, then I'd replace the battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the top picture the  battery slides to the right to come out of that clip (which is the positive terminal), but there is plastic blocking this path.

In the bottom picture those fingers look like negative terminals for the battery.

if you cannot remove the circuit board from the plastic case you will need to connect wires tp the exposed terminals and then connect them to a temporary battery while you cut away the clip and the old battery and find a fay to fit the new battery.

usually connecting a new battery in parallel with an old one is a really bad idea, but CD2032 batteries are so weak that this should not cause any problems because it will only be temporary.

[image]

red: positive wires, connect all three,

blue: negative wires connect both

green:  cut here

black temporary CR2032 battery.

once you have the  old battery out you'll have to decide how to connect the replacement battery.  the negative terminals should be accessible from the back of the device now so soldering a wire here is now an option.

Comment: thanks very much for the infos I cannot make a vote I'm new on the site sorry :(

Comment: as the one posing the request you get to pick the best answer (that's the tick mark thing)

Comment: When you write cut here it's for remove the old battery or other purpose I don't get this point ?

Comment: In fact the battery seems to be CR2016 but the process will be the same I bough this to help me to make the connection https://ibb.co/Gs3pvyr

Answer (score 4):

Just connect a power source (like a new battery) in parallel to keep it alive, then remove the old battery, then stick a SECOND new battery one into the slot of the old one. Like doing a heart transplant.

Comment: I will try I understand the idea now it's how I will connect the new CR2032 maybe  by making a weld not sure is it the best way to do

Comment: @Kalipso photos. weld sounds like asking for an explosion or damage. what you probably need are little probe clips but we need photos

Comment: Like this (https://ibb.co/dmjRhWq)

Comment: you can edit your post and paste it right in

Comment: but man, that is not much to work with. the negative tab is under the battery

Comment: you mean it's not complicated or it's not ok ? Since I can't remove the old battery. the concept seems very simple until it explose on my face :)

Comment: It is going to be tough since you cant come at from any side but the top and it is going to be tough sliding a contact beneath without shorting the batery out

Comment: wait, is the negative terminal accesible from the side? it looks like it might be sticking up at the edge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109313/discussion-between-kalipso-and-dknguyen).

Answer (score 3):

If the battery is at 0V, then isn't that the same effect as removing the battery and putting a new one in?

If it is not at 0V and RAM is still running, then the only way to do it is to somehow do a *quick* swap with a voltage source.  Emphasis on the quick.  As soon as a higher potential is put on the battery, it will try to charge it.  A CR2032 can't be charged for long without something catastrophic happening.

Comment: Or you can connect an adjustable source and match it to the old battery before removing the old one. After the old battery is removed turn up the voltage to match the new battery before sticking it in. You could also connect a new battery with a SMALL resistor (not too large or your system will lose power but this sounds like a very low current device anyways so resistive drop shouldn't be too bad), remove the old battery, short the resistor, then insert a second new battery.